# C++ Counting upwards from one number to another

Tags: c++, counting

So my program has to ask the user to input two numbers and then the program has to figure out which is the lowest number and which is the highest. Then the program counts from the lowest to the highest and displays it (e.g. 3, 4, 5, 6). I think the problems lies in the if else statement but I'm not sure.

```
using namespace std;
void no_1_count_from_min_to_max(int min, int max);
int main()
{
    int min=0;
    int max=4;
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;

    cout<<"Enter first number:";
    cin>>first;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter second number:";
    cin>>second;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter third number:";
    cin>>third;
    cout<<endl;

    no_1_count_from_min_to_max(min,max);

    if (first>second){
        first = max;
        second = min;
    }
    else{
        second = max;
        first = min;
    }
    return 0;
}
    void no_1_count_from_min_to_max(int min, int max){
        for (int i = min; i<=max; i++){
            cout<<setw(4)<<i;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: What problem? It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You ask for user to input some numbers, and then, immediately, overwrite them with your hardcoded values. What is the purpose of asking for numbers, then?

Comment: `first = max` means "set first to the value of max".  I think you're intending to set max?  You're also doing all this AFTER your output.

Comment: Try something simpler. Seriously, you should always try to build up from the simple to the complex, and if you don't know why your code is failing, then try simplifying it.

Comment: If you found solution, don't edit the question stating that you did. Accept the answer which was the solution. If none were - write the answer yourself, and accept it. Otherwise - your edit doesn't convey anything useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You're never modifying `min` or `max`.  You set them to 0 and 4 at the beginning of `main` and never update them.

Comment: Technically - those numbers are `0`, and `4`, not 0, and **1**.